# Oracle Databaseで年毎にfileを分けてexportしたい

Tags: database, oracle

`Windows Server2008R2`上の`Oracle Database11gR2`から`expdp`を利用して、table毎のexportを行いたいのですが、dump fileを1年毎に分割したいです。
いくつかのtableはQUERYオプションを付けることで実現できることを確認できたのですが...

対象のtable自信に日時情報を持たない(他tableと結合しないと年毎のレコードを絞れない)tableに対して、年毎のexportが実現できません。

expdpのQUERYに以下のような指定をしてみましたが、ダメでした。

```
expdp UserID/PASSWORD@TNSNAME ^
 TABLES=A_TBL ^
 DUMPFILE=A_TBL_2014.dmp ^
 LOGFILE=A_TBL_exp2014.log ^
 QUERY=A_TBL:\"WHERE SNO IN (SELECT SNO FROM B_TBL B WHERE '2014-01-01' <= B.DATE AND B.DATE < '2015-01-01');\"
```

コマンド自体は正常終了するのですが、『0行がexportされました』と出力されてしまいます。対象のレコードが有ることは確認できています。
どうにか、日時情報を持たないtableに対して、年毎の絞込を行いつつexportする方法は無いでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

申し訳ありません。自己解決しました。
最後の`\"`の前に`;`を書いてしまっていたのが原因でした。他のSQLからコピペしてきたときに残してしまっていたみたいです。

```
expdp UserID/PASSWORD@TNSNAME ^
 TABLES=A_TBL ^
 DUMPFILE=A_TBL_2014.dmp ^
 LOGFILE=A_TBL_exp2014.log ^
 QUERY=A_TBL:\"WHERE SNO IN (SELECT SNO FROM B_TBL B WHERE '2014-01-01' <= B.DATE AND B.DATE < '2015-01-01')\"
```